# Find sum of two columns of different tables then subtract their sum

Tags: sql, vb6, ms-access-2007

hi I want to make a query that first find the sum of two columns of different table then subtract it
Example
it is a visual basic program

```
Dim large_tbl As String
Dim sell_large As String

large_tbl = "SELECT Sum(No_Of_Bottle) FROM add_cotton where Cateogry='Large'"
sell_large = "SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Sell_Detail where Cateogry='Large'"

Adodc2.RecordSource = large_tbl - sell_large
```

Please help
it shows an error type miss match

Comment: It is `Cateogry` the right name of the column?

Comment: you are subtracting the queries, not the query results. You'll need to run the queries and subtract the results.

Comment: thanks for reply but what the solution will be please tell

Comment: Sam Leach i subtract the result of query first i save the sum in variable then subtract it can you tell whats going wrong

Answer (score 2):

The two variables `large_tbl` and `sell_large` are strings -- just text as far as VB is concerned. You need to connect to a data source (i.e. a Sql Server) and execute a query to get a numerical result.

What you've asked the computer to do is subtract "blah" from "blah" and execute it.

What I guess you meant is something more like:

```
Dim oCNX as ADODB.Connection

:----Put code in here to open the connection to your database

Dim resultA as ADODB.Recordset
Dim resultB as ADODB.Recordset

Dim large_tbl As String
Dim sell_large As String

large_tbl = "SELECT Sum(No_Of_Bottle) FROM add_cotton where Cateogry='Large'"
sell_large = "SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Sell_Detail where Cateogry='Large'"

Set resultA = oCNX.Execute(large_tbl)
Set resultB = oCNX.Execute(sell_large)

Do while not oRS.Eof()

   Debug.Print "Result =" & (resultA(1).Value - resultB(1).Value)

   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Or something like that.

Comment: thanks for reply i am using visual basic 6.0 cen you tell me the syntax(vb)

Comment: This is possible a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788232.aspx

Comment: can you Highlighted where i am getting wrong with my Query